# How to preload a single checkbox in Angular 12?

Tags: angular

I'm trying to preload a checkbox in an *Angular 12* application. I've seen a few examples of doing something similar with AngularJS but they depend on deprecated stuff. I suspect this is quite simple but I'm just not getting it.

In my `app.component.ts` file I have a boolean that gets updated from a API call when the application loads. I want to display that value initially and allow the user to change it later. A change successfully tells the API about the new value.

I think that I need to execute some JS on startup to update the checkbox, but I'm not sure. Anyway all the examples I've found for that are AngularJS so maybe there's a better way?

FWIW this is what my html looks like, though it is fairly obvious.

```
<div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
    <button title="clear" (click)="clear()">clear</button>
    <button title="refresh" (click)="refresh()">refresh</button>
    <label for="quiet">Quiet</label>
    <input id="quiet" type="checkbox" (change)="onChange($event)"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a template driven form (or reactive forms) to accomplish this.

app.componet.ts

```js
constructor() { }

checkboxControl: boolean = true; <- default it to what you need it to be initially
```

in HTML you will need to use `[(ngModel)]` to bind them together.

```html
<div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
    <button title="clear" (click)="clear()">clear</button>
    <button title="refresh" (click)="refresh()">refresh</button>
    <label for="quiet">Quiet</label>
    <input id="quiet" type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="checkboxControl" (change)="onChange($event)"/>
</div>
```

Now in your TS file when you make an API call, you just update or set the checkboxControl value.

```js
getValueFromService() {
  this.service.getCheckboxValue().subscribe(value => {
    this.checkboxControl = value
  }
}
```

Comment: This looks promising. It gives me two errors though:
Error: src/app/app.component.html:8:37 - error NG8002: Can't bind to 'ngModel' since it isn't a known property of 'input'.
and
Error: src/app/app.component.html:8:50 - error TS2322: Type 'Event' is not assignable to type 'boolean'.
The constructor variable and the equivalent function to update it was already there (and fetching the right value). So it is just the connection to the HTML I am missing.

Comment: For your first error, make sure you are importing FormsModule in your app.module.ts.

Comment: For your second error. I would need to see your onChange function to be sure but it seems like you have something like this `onChange(value: boolean)` change it to `onChange(event: any)` then console log event to find the value

Comment: Including FormsModule cleared both errors and fixed the original problem. My onChange event was already expecting event: any. FormsModule was the answer. Thanks for your help.